# How to enable CORS on AWS with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to enable CORS on my aws project which consists of `API Gateway` and `Lambda` function.
I'm creating an API Gateway with `GET` and `OPTIONS` methods.
`OPTIONS` is meant to be a mock endpoint for enabling CORS as per aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).
There is a lambda function (`aws_lambda_function.app_lambda`) which is invoked by `GET` method and in response headers has:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
```

But still, I cannot pass CORS.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
  name        = "appAPIGateway"
  description = "App App App"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "rest_api_resource" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api"]
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part = "playground"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "opt" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
  http_method   = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
  api_key_required = true
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "opt" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.opt.http_method}"
  type = "MOCK"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "opt" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.opt.http_method}"
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'"
  }
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_integration.opt", "aws_api_gateway_method_response.opt"]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "opt" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.opt.http_method}"
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
  }
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.opt"]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "app_api_gateway_method" {
  rest_api_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
  http_method      = "GET"
  authorization    = "NONE"
  api_key_required = true
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "app_cors_method_response_200" {
    rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
    resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
    http_method   = "${aws_api_gateway_method.app_api_gateway_method.http_method}"
    status_code   = "200"
    response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
  }
    depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.app_api_gateway_method"]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "app_api_gateway_integration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_method.app_api_gateway_method.resource_id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.app_api_gateway_method.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = "${aws_lambda_function.app_lambda.invoke_arn}"
  depends_on    = [
    "aws_api_gateway_method.app_api_gateway_method",
    "aws_lambda_function.app_lambda"
    ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "app_api_gateway_integration_response" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.app_api_gateway_method.http_method}"
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'"
  }
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.app_api_gateway_integration",
    "aws_api_gateway_method_response.app_cors_method_response_200",
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "app_api_gateway_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  stage_name  = "app_stage"
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_integration_response.app_api_gateway_integration_response",
    "aws_api_gateway_integration_response.opt"
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreceated.

Answer (score 11):

For newer HTTP API (v2), you can use:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "lambda" {
  name          = "lambda_gw_api"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  cors_configuration {
    allow_origins = ["https://www.mywebsite.fr"]
    allow_methods = ["POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
    allow_headers = ["content-type"]
    max_age = 300
  }
}
```

PS: you may also need to check your OPTIONS route has an "integration" and does not return 401.

Comment: What if there is a custom domain set up? Do I also need to add this domain to the allow_origins argument?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the terraform module to enable cors:

```
module "api-gateway-enable-cors" {
source  = "squidfunk/api-gateway-enable-cors/aws"
version = "0.3.3"
api_id          = "<your_api_id>"
api_resource_id = "<your_api_resource_id>"
}
```

Source : [api-gateway-enable-cors](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/squidfunk/api-gateway-enable-cors/aws/0.3.1)

Comment: Use version 0.3.3 if on terraform >= 0.12 to avoid error in function call because of use of deprecated "map" funcion

Comment: Outdated module, does not work on never terraform versions

Answer (score 2):

Found out a simple solution. The problem was that on applying newer changes to existing API Gateway, was NOT re-deploying those gateways. So I had to redeploy them by myself manually and think of how to do that in terraform too.

Comment: You can do an auto deployment using: 
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "rest_api" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.body))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

It is useful to check the API GW logs in Cloudwatch to see what is the status code. In my scenario, I had two routes configured with `aws_apigatewayv2_route`, one for POST and one for OPTIONS, for the same route key. The OPTIONS request was failing with statuscode `429` which is too many requests. This status code is usually returned by throttling settings when its over allowed limit.

Turns out, since the OPTIONS request was not passing CORS, it was because I did not specify throttling in `default_route_settings` in terraform, so the default throttling for "Default route throttling" was defaulting to `0` for burst and rate. So my OPTIONS request was not passing CORS because it was getting hit by this throttling defaulting to zero. The hint in AWS console is clear:

> This throttling limit applies to each route in the stage except those
> defined for specific routes.

Moral of the story - on your OPTIONS requests, really pay attention to the status code returned by API GW, and check the Cloudwatch logs for API GW.
So: all worked, when I added this in terraform, under my `resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "lambda"`:

```
   default_route_settings {
      throttling_burst_limit  = 1000 
      throttling_rate_limit   = 5000
    }
```